# wscript.quit parameter not available in batch error level

Tags: vb6, vbscript, batch-file, wsh

A simple VBScript containing the single line `wscript.quit(2)`, called from a batch script does not pass the quit parameter value into the batch errorlevel variable as it should - the batch file only echos the default error level (0).

I recently uninstalled VB6 (necessary for clean installation of VB.net) and I think this may be, at least, part of the problem.  In building a work-around to pass the results of a VBScripting message box to a calling batch file, I found that the scripting file system object (scrrun.dll) had been unregistered by the uninstallation and it was necessary to re-register it to instantiate the object.  I'm wondering if there is some other dependency which is required by wscript.exe to give the *quit* function access to the batch error level variable.

I ran wscript.exe under ***Dependency Walker*** for the aforementioned one line VBScript and the only error message I got during the execution was the following:

**GetProcAddress(0x755C0000 [MSCTFIME.IME], "ImeGetImeMenuItems") called from "IMM32.DLL" at address 0x76397354 and returned NULL. Error: The specified procedure could not be found (127).**

The script terminated with the proper *quit* code (2).

The dll mentioned exists in the System32 folder with WScript and is unregisterable.

I'm running WinXP with all the latest updates.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Side note, VB6 and VB.NET coexist just fine.  They are wholely unrelated development environments.

Comment: I tried replicating what you described and it worked for me. Can you show us your batch file code?

Comment: for me too. Maybe you are invoking wscript thru a secondary CMD?

Comment: Why the goofy extraneous parens around the value?

Comment: tcarvin: Here in our shop, everyone who has installed vb.net has trashed their vb6 installation.  We found it better to just uninstall it.

Comment: aphoria / PA.: I expected it to work for others who tried it - I think there is a problem with my configuration and I was hoping that someone else who had a similar problem would also have a solution.

Comment: Bob Riemersma: Sorry, Bob - just habit.

Answer (score 4):

Windows GUI programs aren't meant for console use; so they most often return False == 0 to the OS. **Wscript.exe** is such a program. If you want to use a .vbs from a .bat/.cmd/.exe console program, call it via **Cscript.exe**.

Evidence for Bob:

```
type el.vbs
WScript.Quit 2 ' no () when calling a Sub

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

cscript el.vbs

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
2  <======= cscript.exe sets ERRORLEVEL

type el.vbs
WScript.Quit 2 ' no () when calling a Sub

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0  <======= ERRORLEVEL is (re)set to 0

wscript el.vbs

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0  <======= wscript.exe does not set ERRORLEVEL
```

QED for VBScript 5.7.16599 * cscript 5.7

Update: Thanks to Bob's comment, I found

[this **correct** explanation and remedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592075/why-doesnt-winmain-set-the-errorlevel/592148#592148)

evidence:

```
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0

start /wait wscript el.vbs

echo %ERRORLEVEL%
2
```

So even Windows GUI programs can/will report status by returning an appropriate value from _tWinMain - you'll just have to /wait (resp. .Run( sCmd, nShow, **True** ) to pick it up.

Comment: Ekkehard Horner: I had high hopes that you were on to something but using START with the wait parameter doesn't work for me.  Like I said, this is a configuration problem.  I have seen other examples where the error level is returned properly, whether the script is called by wscript or cscript.